# What is solid-phase bridge amplification?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, dna-sequencing

During Illumina sequencing there is a step called bridge amplification by which DNA is amplified by isothermal enzymes. What is this stage, and how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stage is after the adsorption of the adapter-ligated fragments on the flow cells. 
The fragments are isothermally amplified to generate clusters [[1](https://ncifrederick.cancer.gov/atp/cms/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/CustomerIlluminaTechExplanation.pdf)]. The exact nature of the enzyme mix that catalyses this step is not disclosed by Illumina. **I assume** it must be similar to **[Helicase mediated isothermal amplification](http://www.nature.com/embor/journal/v5/n8/fig_tab/7400200_F1.html)**, which uses helicase and single strand-binding proteins (SSB) to denature the template. The polymerization is catalysed by a mesophilic DNA-Pol such as Klenow (*E.coli*).